# Would it be incorrect to use the html 5 canvas element as a cross for a pop up?

Tags: html, canvas, element

When I say incorrect, obviously the thing will work - but is there anything illegal, wrong or invalid about using it in that way?

Say just for a (x) button to close a window?  (Obviously with the image stated in the CSS and no content in the element).

I know there are a wide choice of elements that could be used, `<button>`, `<div>`, `<span>` etc.. but is this completely wrong or is it fine?

Comment: I'd say "browser support. Why not use an `<img>`?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`canvas`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) element is not supported by IE8 and lower, so you cannot rely on a `canvas` if you are going to support IE8.

Also, my guess is that the canvas solution might be less performant than a simple image.

Comment: Browser support would be quite easily fixed by the html5shiv `js` file.  Other than that, there's nothing really 'wrong' with using it for the purpose that I have said, is there?